# Chrome and Safari on iOS crashes on our page

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, mobile-safari

We work on a page and when we test it on chrome on iOS. chrome crashes immediately without any errormessage. The same for Safari.

What possibilities do I have to debug it? Or how can I find out what causes the crash?

Chrome is up-to-date

When I test the page with chrome Dev Tools I see a memory spike when the page is loaded. The spike goes up to ~12MB. Some pages says there can be a problem on iOS Safari when the page use more then 10MB memory. 
I'm not sure safari/chrome crashes cause of too much memory. It's just a guess.

Is there any possible to not have the spike? What can I do?

Comment: If your page is using that much memory then you should probably take steps to reduce it (use smaller images, lazy loading..) Without knowing what your page does its hard to tell.

Comment: @Graham: There are much javascript libraries that get loaded when the page is loading. I don't know if that's true, but I thinkn when all the libraries get loaded chrome makes much hashtables and stuff to store all the JavaScript Objects and in that process chrome uses much memory. Lazy loading would be an option then

Comment: Have you tried loading page without those javascript libraries?

Comment: @VilleRouhiainen: I think its a combination of Javascript, CSS, ?. With less CSS the browsers crashes only on some pages. And yes, without any JS the page does not crash.